# Ошибка каскадных таблиц (Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Tags: c#, база-данных, update

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема с созданием таблицы. Ошибка в Package Manager Console :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Ticket_TicketId' on table 'Orders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Код:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Orders")]
public class OrderEntity : IDbEntity
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TicketId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TicketId")]
    public TicketSetupEntity TicketSetup { get; set; }

    public int PerformerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PerformerId")]
    public UserEntity Performer { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
 public class TicketSetupEntity : AbstractTicketEntity
    {

        public int FacilityConsumerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FacilityConsumerId")]
        public FacilityConsumerEntity FacilityConsumer { get; set; }


    }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Ticket")]
    public abstract class AbstractTicketEntity : IDbEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
        public TicketTypeEntity Type { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public int CreatorId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
        public UserEntity Creator { get; set; }

        public int? AssignedId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AssignedId")]
        public UserEntity Assigned { get; set; }

    }
```

Почитав различные ссылки, предположила что это происходит из-за того что в классе OrderEntity есть свойство Performer а также TicketSetup и в свою очередь TicketSetup содержит тоже ссылку на ту же таблицу что и Performer. В рекомендациях было написано составить какие то ограничения каскадных таблиц.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderEntity>().HasRequired(oo => oo.TicketSetup).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderEntity>().HasRequired(oo => oo.Performer).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Но когда я так делаю вместо того чтобы просто ссылаться на имеющиеся записи в таблицах Tickets и Users создаются дублирующие записи. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в ситуации.

Добавляю код сохранения:

```
        internal static int SaveOrderForTicket(DTOOrder order)
    {
        _log.Info("SaveOrderForTicket: IdTicket={0}", order.TicketSetup.Id);

        try
        {
            using (AssistanceCenterDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new AssistanceCenterDatabaseFactory())
            {
                IRepository<OrderEntity> repository = AssistanceCenterRepositoryFactory.Instance.GetRepository<OrderEntity>();

                IRepository<TicketSetupEntity> ticketRepository = AssistanceCenterRepositoryFactory.Instance.GetRepository<TicketSetupEntity>(dbFactory);
                IRepository<UserEntity> userRepository = AssistanceCenterRepositoryFactory.Instance.GetRepository<UserEntity>(dbFactory);
                OrderEntity entity = _mappingWrapper.Map<DTOOrder, OrderEntity>(order);

                TicketSetupEntity ticketEntity;
                UserEntity userEntity;

                ticketEntity = ticketRepository.GetOne((t) => t.Id == entity.TicketSetup.Id);
                userEntity = userRepository.GetOne((u) => u.Id == entity.Performer.Id);
                entity.TicketSetup = ticketEntity;
                entity.Performer = userEntity;

                if (entity.Id == 0)
                {
                    repository.Create(entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    repository.Update(entity);
                }
                return entity.Id;
            }

        }
```

Comment: У вас в вопросе упомянуты 2 совершенно разные проблемы. К тому же, первую вы уже самостоятельно решили - а про вторую не указали никаких подробностей.

Comment: Уберите из своего вопроса все, что касается уже решенной проблемы, и приведите какие именно дублирующиеся записи у вас создаются. Хотелось бы увидеть код, который создает эти самые записи, то, что находится в БД после работы этого кода - а также класс UserEntity.

Comment: я не уверена на сколько решена проблема первая как вы считаете возможно я не верно написала ограничения для каскада и поэтому происходит такая ситуация при сохраненни (((

Comment: Первая проблема решена вами полностью. Вторая никак не связана с первой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разрешила ситуацию тем что прописала в автомапере настроки полностью для этих элементов:

```
        _mappingWrapper.CreateMap<DTOOrder, OrderEntity>()
            .ForMember(c => c.TicketSetup, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(p => p.Performer, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(p => p.PerformerId, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Performer.Id))
             .ForMember(p => p.TicketId, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.TicketSetup.Id))
            .ReverseMap();
```

после чего как и посоветовал Pavel Mayorov сократила код, убрала лишние репозитории.

```
internal static int SaveOrderForTicket(DTOOrder order)
{
    _log.Info("SaveOrderForTicket: IdTicket={0}", order.TicketSetup.Id);

        using (AssistanceCenterDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new AssistanceCenterDatabaseFactory())
        {
            IRepository<OrderEntity> repository = AssistanceCenterRepositoryFactory.Instance.GetRepository<OrderEntity>();

            OrderEntity entity = _mappingWrapper.Map<DTOOrder, OrderEntity>(order);     

            if (entity.Id == 0)
            {
                repository.Create(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                repository.Update(entity);
            }
            return entity.Id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу, вы сначала заполняете `entity.TicketSetup` и `entity.Performer` - а потом получаете их из базы и снова заполняете, к тому же все сильно "приправлено" репозиториями...

Попробуйте упрощать ваш код, убирая из него слои абстракции, до тех пор пока ошибка не пропадет или не станет очевидной. Ошибка явно не в этом коде, а где-то в этих самых слоях абстракции.

На всякий случай, вот то же самое, но написанное проще:

```
        using (var db = GetDatabaseContext() /* не знаю, как сделать это в вашем проекте */ )
        {
            var entity = _mappingWrapper.Map<DTOOrder, OrderEntity>(order);
            db.Entry(entity.TicketSetup).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(entity.Performer).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return entity.Id;
        }
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь))